# is there a way in R to return values with wild cards for certain characters?

Tags: r

say I have something like:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c(1, 1, 1,2,2,2,2),
               value=c('ABC000', 'ABC002', 'ABC003', 'ACC000', 'ABC005', 'ABC006', 'ABC007'),
               keep=c(1, 0, 1,0,0,1,0))

  ID  value keep
1  1 ABC000    1
2  1 ABC002    0
3  1 ABC003    1
4  2 ACC000    0
5  2 ABC005    0
6  2 ABC006    1
7  2 ABC007    0
```

and say I want to keep values where the prefix is 'ABC', I don't care what the values are in the fourth and fifth character, and then the last place has to be 0, 3 or 6. Is there a way in R to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stringr` functions and and regex like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(value, pattern = "^ABC.{2}(0|3|6)$"))

#   ID  value keep
# 1  1 ABC000    1
# 2  1 ABC003    1
# 3  2 ABC006    1
```

Deconstructing the detection pattern as follows:

- The string should start with `^ABC`, where `^` anchors the front of the string,
- `.{2}` where `.` is your "wildcard" character and I specify that there are two (`{2}`),
- and `(0|3|6)$` finally I say that the string ends with either 0, 3, or 6 (where `$` anchors the end of the string)

## Edit

User mentioned in comments interest in creating a new field that flags whether `value` field matches the specified condition.

You can add a new field using `mutate` and `if_else` as follows:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(flag = if_else(str_detect(value, pattern = "^ABC.{2}[036]$"), 1, 0))

#   ID  value keep flag
# 1  1 ABC000    1    1
# 2  1 ABC002    0    0
# 3  1 ABC003    1    1
# 4  2 ACC000    0    0
# 5  2 ABC005    0    0
# 6  2 ABC006    1    1
# 7  2 ABC007    0    0
```

The `if_else` statement assigns the value 1 for matching the pattern and 0 when it doesn't.

Comment: I like this, but can you explain what ^ and . etc is doing

Comment: @biostatguy12 I added commentary to my answer

Comment: @thelatemail I thought that'd work but it doesn't work for me, hmm

Comment: @OTStats - works for me - `df$value[grepl("^ABC.{2}[036]$", df$value)]` , as does `df %>% filter(str_detect(value, pattern = "^ABC.{2}[036]$"))`

Comment: @thelatemail Ah, I had to change my parentheses to square brackets! thanks for sharing!

Comment: @OTStats any way to do this without filtering? ie maybe thru a mutate ifelse to get keep==1? I have to do a few steps

Comment: @biostatguy12 see the edit! I think that's what you were going for.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
value[startsWith(value, "ABC") & grepl("[036]$", value)]
# [1] "ABC000" "ABC003" "ABC006"
```

To create a new column with 1s and 0s for the condition being `TRUE` or not you can do

```
+(startsWith(value, "ABC") & grepl("[036]$", value))
# [1] 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

**data**

```
value=c('ABC000', 'ABC002', 'ABC003', 'ACC000', 'ABC005', 'ABC006', 'ABC007')
```